# For @SpringBootTest, why am I told "Configuration error: found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith" even though I don't have a single one?

Tags: jpa, spring-security, integration-testing, spring-boot-test, spring-boot-2

I'm using Spring Boot 2.1.  I'm trying to set up a Spring Boot integration test to test a controller.  I have the below

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes=CardmaniaApplication.class)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@DataJpaTest
public class CardControllerIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private ICardRepository cardRepository;

    @Autowired
    private IUserRepository userRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private IOccasionRepository occasionRepository;
    
    @Test
    @WithMockUser(authorities = {"ADMIN"})
    void createCard() throws Exception {
        final Card card = new Card();
        final User author = userRepository.findAll().get(0);
        card.setAuthor(author);
        final Occasion occasion = occasionRepository.findAll().get(0);
        card.setOccasion(occasion);
        byte[] image = new byte[] {1, 1, 1, 1};
        card.setImage(image);
        
        mockMvc.perform(post("/api/cards").contentType("application/json")
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(card)))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());

        List<Card> cards = cardRepository.findByOccasion(occasion);
        assertThat(cards.size()).isEqualTo(1);
        final Card cardEntity = cards.get(0);
        assertThat(cardEntity.getImage()).isEqualTo(image);
    }
}
```

I'm a little confused about how to annotate the main class, because when I run the test, I get the exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Configuration error: found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith for test class [com.burrobuie.cardmania.controller.CardControllerIntegrationTest]: [@org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper), @org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper)]
    at org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.resolveExplicitTestContextBootstrapper(BootstrapUtils.java:166)
    at org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.resolveTestContextBootstrapper(BootstrapUtils.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:122)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.lambda$getOrComputeIfAbsent$0(ExtensionValuesStore.java:81)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$MemoizingSupplier.get(ExtensionValuesStore.java:182)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(ExtensionValuesStore.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(ExtensionValuesStore.java:88)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.NamespaceAwareStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(NamespaceAwareStore.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.getTestContextManager(SpringExtension.java:213)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.beforeAll(SpringExtension.java:77)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeAllCallbacks$7(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:359)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeAllCallbacks(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:359)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:189)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:78)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:132)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
    Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Configuration error: found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith for test class [com.burrobuie.cardmania.controller.CardControllerIntegrationTest]: [@org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper), @org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper)]
        at org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.resolveExplicitTestContextBootstrapper(BootstrapUtils.java:166)
        at org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.resolveTestContextBootstrapper(BootstrapUtils.java:127)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:122)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.lambda$getOrComputeIfAbsent$0(ExtensionValuesStore.java:81)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$MemoizingSupplier.get(ExtensionValuesStore.java:182)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.remove(ExtensionValuesStore.java:98)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.NamespaceAwareStore.remove(NamespaceAwareStore.java:73)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.afterAll(SpringExtension.java:89)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterAllCallbacks$13(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:425)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterAllCallbacks$14(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:425)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeAfterAllCallbacks(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:425)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.after(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:213)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.after(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:78)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:145)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:145)
    

... 29 more
```

What do I need to add or remove to my header to allow my test to run?

I have to include the following because SO tells me my question is mostly code.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Comment: Umm.. because both `@SpringBootTest` and `@DataJpaTest` are meta-annotated with `@BootstrapWith`, with conflicting bootstrapers specified? You're not supposed to mix the two annotations together. If you're not sure which one to use, use `@SpringBootTest`

Comment: Also, you don't need a separate `@ContextConfiguration` annotation. Just use `@SpringBootTest(classes = CardmaniaApplication.class)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple conflicting test annotations in place. For your use case: integration test for your controller, the following setup is enough:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class CardControllerIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private ICardRepository cardRepository;

    @Autowired
    private IUserRepository userRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private IOccasionRepository occasionRepository;
    
    @Test
    @WithMockUser(authorities = {"ADMIN"})
    void createCard() throws Exception {
        final Card card = new Card();
        final User author = userRepository.findAll().get(0);
        card.setAuthor(author);
        final Occasion occasion = occasionRepository.findAll().get(0);
        card.setOccasion(occasion);
        byte[] image = new byte[] {1, 1, 1, 1};
        card.setImage(image);
        
        mockMvc.perform(post("/api/cards").contentType("application/json")
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(card)))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());

        List<Card> cards = cardRepository.findByOccasion(occasion);
        assertThat(cards.size()).isEqualTo(1);
        final Card cardEntity = cards.get(0);
        assertThat(cardEntity.getImage()).isEqualTo(image);
    }
}
```

Explanation:

- `@DataJpaTest` is used to test database-related slices of your
  application (e.g. repositories) in isolation
- `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` is redundant as it comes already
  with `@SpringBootTest`
- `@ContextConfiguration` is redundant, as `@SpringBootTest` makes sure to
  create your context

With this setup, you are now able to start the whole Spring Context (without the embedded servlet container) and can access your endpoints with `MockMvc`. Ensure you have configured access to a database for your integration tests, e.g. you can use [Testcontainers](https://rieckpil.de/howto-write-spring-boot-integration-tests-with-a-real-database/) for this.

If you also want to start Tomcat and use e.g. `TestRestTemplate` or `WebTestClient` to access you endpoints without `MockMvc`, use the following: `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)`

You can always take a look at the source code of the annotations to understand what they will enable in the background (e.g. CTRL + left click in IDEA). `@SpringBootTest`, for example, looks like the following:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Inherited
@BootstrapWith(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.class)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public @interface SpringBootTest {

}
```